# How do I create a Dell Utility Partition on new hard drive?

Tags: windows-vista, raid-0, boot-partition

Installed new HD on Dell Vista PC with RAIDd 0 configuration. I cannot boot from the Dell Reinstallation Windows VISTA DVD. Getting message that there's no Dell Utility partition, which was wiped with the new HD and RAID 0. Cannot boot from DVD drive although I've selected from BIOS menu.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a helpful point here on the reinstallation of the Dell Utility partition with links to DL. You would need your product type and model.

This link may put you in the right direction.[Dell utility partition](http://lists.us.dell.com/pipermail/linux-precision/2007-March/001146.html)